# Mission control - application windows cascade view

Tags: macos, dock, mission-control, expose

I'm struggling to find a solution for displaying Application Windows into a stacked/grouped/cascade view. I'd like to point out that i'm not referring to the general Mission Control which displays all aplication windows. I'm referring when displaying windows of the same app.

For example now (by default) is shows like this http://screencast.com/t/X4IlAs5Dj .
The problem is **i can barely see the tabs inside Chrome** and i have to either remember perfectly in which window i had a certain tab or just click on them until i find the right window.

What i'd like would be to display the windows like this: http://screencast.com/t/RBqdpevli
Having them like this would be straight to the point. No wasted time nor clicks.

I know about the option called "Group windows by application", but this only applies to the general Mission control on all opened apps, not a certain one.

Thanks!

PS: I'm on MacBook Pro with Retina display, OS X Mavericks (10.9.5)

Answer (score 1):

During your app expose, you can hover the mouse on the window you want and press the Space Bar to enlarge it allowing you to have a sneak peak in full size. It works in mission control too.

[image: Enlarged window in App Exposé]

Also in mission control you can move your mouse to the app and scroll up to scatter the app windows, then you can use the Space Bar to have a sneak peak of the window at full size.

[image: Scattered Safari windows in mission control]

Comment: Thanks for the tip, knew about that, but still somehow this feels painful as you have to do something repetitive instead of a simpler view that is straight to the target.

Comment: Aah. I agree. I think Apple should consider App-specific expose effects. Or even better, allow apps to display their own expose pattern.